# What is the difference between explanatory, descriptive, and predictive analysis?

Tags: social-epistemology

What is the difference between explanatory, descriptive, and predictive analysis? If one accepts the argument that we cannot hope to explain why/how someone from another culture acts, then how can we predict it?

Answer (score 6):

A descriptive analysis involves simply stating the facts as they are. A descriptive analysis should not at any point provide any conclusions or generalizations. At most a  descriptive analysis may involved providing summaries, descriptive statistics such as means, standard deviations, and graphs and visualizations to better understand the data. In your cultural example such an analysis will describe the characteristics of the culture and the historical and geographic context in which it arose. You are looking for the "what".

An explanatory analysis will try not only to describe the information but also to provide causal relationships between the various data presented. Again in your cultural example, such an analysis will provide reasons for why that specific cultural arose from that specific context, why a historical event or climactic feature led to a specific behavioral trait. When we're dealing with quantitative and statistical data, a descriptive analysis will simply provide means, standard deviations, and graphs while an explanatory analysis also provides some mathematical models tying the variables together which explain the influence they have on each other. You no longer just describe the facts, you also describe the cause and effect relationship between the facts. You are looking for the "why".

The predictive analysis is just going one step further than the explanatory analysis and applying the relationships of mathematical models that were discovered to previously unknown data and future cases. In Your cultural example, you have to be able to explain how the geographic and historical context influenced the behavior of individuals from that culture well enough that based on that, you can predict how such an individual would react to a completely new situation. You are looking for the "what if".

---

It should be noted that in the field of Pattern Recognition, some methods, such as Neural Networks, are able to predict variables based on inputs without providing any explanatory model for their predictions.

Comment: Alexander: Thank you for the detailed response. Question though: You say that predictive analysis is going one step further than explanatory analysis. But, can't we predict (within some probability distribution) social phenomena that we can's explain? For example, I might not be able to explain why someone commits a terrorist act. But, some models can arguably predict terrorist attacks within some probability distribution.

Comment: @EVolk you are correct. Some models do predict without providing an explanation: Neural Networks are a famous example. I don't know how they would fit in your cultural behavior/likelihood of a terrorist attack problem. For starters I don't know that anybody can predict terrorist attacks with any likelihood unless they use intelligence information, (which does provide causal information). Continued next comment -

Comment: Second you will note that I qualified my statement: "how the geographic and historical context influenced the behavior of individuals from that culture **well enoug** that based on that," . I thin we are very far from being able to make predictions based on psycho-cultural models of terrorists, any more than we are able to predict why most mass-shootings in the US are perpetrated by white males based on the current state of psychiatry.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question fron the title in the realm of science:

In general science starts from empiricism and takes empiricism as the benchmark for its success.

Hence the first step in science is to make precise observation and to describe in a neutral way what has been observed. This step is **description**.

The next step is to create a theory which allows to derive from it the observed results as well as not yet observed facts. The theory must have a much broader scope than the orginal observations. E.g., the General theory of Relativity covers much more than the three classical effects: bending of light, precession of perihelion of mercury and gravitational redshift. Accordingly the scientific theory is considered an **explanation** of the observations.

Finally, the theory must **predict** the outcome of further observations and experiments on related fields.

One can discuss whether the mathematical theory of quantum mechanics, e.g., centered around the Schroedinger equation, only predicts the outcome of measurements or even explains them.

My answer about science aims at any empirical science, hence also at ethnology or empirical psychology.